# How to put css code in php request id?

Tags: php, css

I would like to add a css code (display:none) against a class (rows) in php request id when that request Id is called. Can anyone help me on this?

In a particular id no. 434, I want to add some css code against a class named "rows". So when 434 id is called, the class named by "rows" will be hidden by css code (ex. display:none). How I am going to do it. Right now I have done something like this:

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['id']=='434'){
?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Need your kind help on this.

The page structure where I am going to put the code is like the following:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
?>

<div class="search<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a CSS definition in your HTML file in case your request `ID` is equal to 434.

Use `!important` keyword to override CSS definition in your main CSS file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="yourmainstylesheet.css"/>
    <?php
      if($_REQUEST['id']=='434'){
    ?>
    <style>
      .rows {
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>  
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but its not working on my page..maybe the main css isn't linked up with it.

Comment: @indy It should work without a main css. Maybe, something's wrong with `$_REQUEST['id]'`. Are you sure it is actually equal to 434?

Comment: it is equal to 434 but really don't know why it's not happening. The structure is in joomla so that id is called like Itemid and I have checked in both conditon, id and Itemid and results are same. No effect on the page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:(inside your if) and above the HTML in your code

```
$myClasses="rows rowsNoDisplay";
```

HTML:

```
<div class="<?php echo $myClasses?>">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rowsNoDisplay{
    display:none;
}
```